# Php corrupted image upload

Tags: php, image, upload, gd

I have a photo upload area. it was working without any problems. But then I started to notice that it didn't upload some images. in others, colors and pixels began to appear incorrect. No problems with old files. only some of the new uploads.
This problem started to occur on its own without any changes in my codes.
I'm cropping a photo using cropper js.
not every upload is like this. I leave the interesting examples here.
sometimes it doesn't load the image at all.
How can something that works properly fail by itself?
sorry my bad english. thanks in advance to everyone who helped

```
 $file = $_FILES['avatar'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['avatar']['error'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){

        if($fileError === 0){

            if($fileSize < 100000000){

                $fileNameNew = time().md5(time().$o_id.$fileName)."_".sha1($user_id.rand(10,99)).$l_category.".".$fileActualExt;

                $fileDestination = "photos/".$fileNameNew;


                function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

                    $info = getimagesize($source);

                    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
                        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

                    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

                    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

                    return true;

                }



                compressImage($fileTmpName, $fileDestination, 90);

            }
```

[image]

Comment: You're cropping the images with a Javascript tool, and compressing them with GD. Do you see these problems if you omit those operations?

Comment: No. Maybe gd library error.
I found out that there might be problems due to corrupt files that were previously loaded. But i have 30000 files:(

Comment: Now the photos get corrupted even if I upload the photo file to a different cdn server without cropping it :( I said no in the answer above, but when I test it again, I see that the photo uploaded to my server is directly corrupted. Very interesting.. how can this be?

Answer (score 1):

I would check if these are filetype related or not. First and last one could be paletted PNG with shifted or partially applied/recognised palette.
The middle one should be a processing error as it has a visible split of contrast in the upper part.

Should be sort of autoexposure that is running on them and fails to do it's job well?

I would say this isn't upload or file error as that'll cause the file to be roken totally 'after' the error and most likely GD won't do a getimagesize() on them nor can use those files.

Also some PHP-related hints:

The pathinfo() is used to get the 'last' extension.

```
$fileActualExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

That imagecreatefrom* is pain in the ass, but you can use a helper to make it better, also you should use the getimagesize(), imagejpeg() and iamgecreatefrom*() return values for checking if they were really okay.

```
function getGDImage($source) {
    if (!($info = getimagesize($source))) {
        return false;
    }

    switch($info['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg': return imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        case 'image/gif': return  imagecreatefromgif($source);
        case 'image/png': return imagecreatefrompng($source);
        default: return false;
    }
}


function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    return ($image = getGDImage($source))
        ? imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality)
        : false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now the photos get corrupted even if I upload the photo file to a different cdn server without cropping it :( I said no in the answer above, but when I test it again, I see that the photo uploaded to my server is directly corrupted. Very interesting.. how can this be?