VichUploaderBundle Sometimes Images are uploaded with broken pixels
Sometimes randomly, uploaded images are broken. The user reuploads the image again and again, it breaks on different places, until eventually it shows correctly.



Q
A




Bundle version
v2.4.2


Symfony version
v6.4.13


PHP version
v8.3.13





https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/f5b61476-9240-4d1d-b1de-11ce0cd5f61d (client video)
There is no obvious pattern on the images that are uploaded as broken. On those images, eventually, after 3-5-10 retries they are uploaded correctly. I use almost the default configuration of the bundle with nothing added in it.
The vich_uploader.yaml file:
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    metadata:
        type: attribute

    mappings:
        uploads:
            # uri_prefix: /uploads
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/%current_date%'
            namer: App\Namer\VichUploadWithDatedPathNamer

The namer class I created:
class VichUploadWithDatedPathNamer implements NamerInterface
{
    public function name($object, PropertyMapping $mapping): string
    {
        /* @var $file UploadedFile */
        $file = $mapping->getFile($object);

        // create path with filename
        $filepath = implode('/', [
            // $mapping->getUriPrefix(),
            date('Y', time()),
            date('m', time()),
            date('d', time()),
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);

        return $filepath;
    }
}

The fields I use inside entities:
// NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'uploads', fileNameProperty: 'featuredImage')]
    private ?File $featuredImageFile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $featuredImage = null;
    
    
    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null $imageFile
     */
    public function setFeaturedImageFile(?File $featuredImageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->featuredImageFile = $featuredImageFile;

        if (null !== $featuredImageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updated = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getFeaturedImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->featuredImageFile;
    }
    

It was working fine for like 1 year or so, and from last week, this started to happen.

Did the client switch camera's by any chance or does it happen to multiple users?

1 user, different cameras in general I believe.
He sends me the image in zip, as much as I upload, i can never recreate it.

I found something similar although no definitive solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053436/php-corrupted-image-upload
